# Adding a constant value to unix file whilst keeping tab

Tags: unix

I have the following tab separated file

```
1   879375  879375
1   899892  899892
1   949363  949363
1   949523  949523
1   949696  949696
1   949739  949739
1   955619  955619
1   957605  957605
1   957693  957693
```

and have used the following unix command to add 1 to each of the values in column 3:

```
awk '{$3+=1}1' file > new_file
```

However the new file loses its tab separator and I would like to keep it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on right path. You need to set `FS`(field separator) and `OFS`(output field separator) as `\t` to your code.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$3+=1}1' Input_file
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I was out for a while! Yes works great, thanks a lot

Comment: @BritishBioinformatician, your welcome, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: I'm not sure if its worth posting another question as the issue is virtually the same, 

In a similar vein I have a file:
`1 22469318 22469539`
`1 22469318 22469539`
`16 222825 223026`
`16 222825 223026`
`16 222825 223026`

And now want to count the number of repeats and create a column with the result. I have used `sort file | uniq -c ` but this doesn't create a new column with a tab separator.

Comment: @BritishBioinformatician, In my humble opinion it will be better to open a new question with same unix tag and let me know url of question, we can discuss on same then, cheers.

Comment: Hi, I have created a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68259666/how-to-count-number-of-duplicate-rows-and-populate-a-new-tab-separated-column