# How to count number of duplicate rows and populate a new tab separated column

Tags: unix

I have the following dataset:

```
1   22469318    22469539
1   22469318    22469539
16  222825  223026
16  222825  223026
16  222825  223026
16  222825  223026
16  222825  223026
16  222825  223026
16  222825  223026
16  222825  223026
16  222825  223026
16  222825  223026
16  222825  223026
16  222825  223026
16  222825  223026
16  222825  223026
16  222825  223026
16  222825  223026
16  222825  223026
16  222825  223026
16  222825  223026
16  222825  223026
16  222825  223026
17  79989511    79989692
19  18717331    18717680
19  18717331    18717680
2   131355420   131355575
2   131355420   131355575
22  51135971    51136163
```

And would like to create a data frame with no duplicated lines but a value indicating how often a duplicate occurred for that row. For example for the above data set I used

```
sort file | uniq -c > new_file
```

and get the following output

```
 2 1    22469318    22469539
     21 16  222825  223026
      1 17  79989511    79989692
      2 19  18717331    18717680
      2 2   131355420   131355575
      4 22  51135971    51136163
      1 5   70240464    70240600
      4 9   140513423   140513521
     22 X   153792513   153793281
```

but I would like the count data in a separate column with a tab separator for example:

```
1       22469318        22469539        2
16      222825          223026          21
17      79989511        79989692        1
19      18717331        18717680        2
2       131355420   131355575   2
22      51135971        51136163        4
5       70240464        70240600        1
9       140513423   140513521   4
X   153792513   153793281   22
```

Comment: By which value you want to sort it? From 1st field, 2nd field or whole line? Please confirm once.

Comment: It will be Good to post an expected output of yours too in your question, thank you.

Comment: Hi, sorting is not important but I would like to find whole line duplicates like for the lines starting with 16 above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code once.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {arr[$0]++} END{for(i in arr){print arr[i],i}}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code here.

```
awk '               ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{              ##Starting BEGIN section of this program.
  FS=OFS="\t"       ##Setting FS, OFS as tab here.
}
{
  arr[$0]++         ##Creating array with index of current line and keep adding its value to it.
}
END{                ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  for(i in arr){    ##Traversing through arr here.
    print arr[i],i  ##Printing array value and key here.
  }
}
' Input_file        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Once you confirm its working fine, will add detailed explanation in it.

Comment: Yes this works fine thanks, is there a simple way of adding the count data to the end of the data frame

Comment: @BritishBioinformatician, Trust me this is a simple way :) to get count at last of line try following once `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {arr[$0]++} END{for(i in arr){print i,arr[i]}}'  file` let me know if this helps you.

Comment: @BritishBioinformatician, Your welcome, I have added detailed explanation for above too, cheers and happy learning.